# Python/Scrapy scraping from Techcrunch

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to build a spider to scrape some Data from the website [Techcrunch - Heartbleed search](https://techcrunch.com/search/heartbleed#stq=heartbleed&stp=1)

my tought was to give a tag when executing the spider from the command line (example: Heartbleed). The spider should then search trough all the associated search results, open each link and get the data contained within.

```
import scrapy


class TechcrunchSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tech_search"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://techcrunch.com/'
        tag = getattr(self, 'tag', None)
        if tag is not None:
            url = url + '?s=' + tag
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

`this code can be executed with : scrapy crawl tech_search -s DOWNLOAD_DELAY=1.5 -o tech_search.jl -a tag=EXAMPLEINPUT"`

Getting the data from the individual pages is not the problem, but actually getting the url to them is(from the search page linked above):

the thing is , when looking at the source Html file (Ctrl + u) of the Search site(link above), then i cant find anything about the searched elements(example : "What Is Heartbleed? The Video"). Any suggestions how to obtain these elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you define your `scrapy` `class` along the lines shown in this answer but using the `PhantomJS` `selenium` headless browser. The essential problem is that when `scrapy` downloads those pages it uses `javascript` code to build the HTML (DOM) that you see but cannot access via the route you have chosen.

Comment: Helpfull as always! Thanks